# mysql select 1 large string or multiple smaller strings

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an app that uses 3 strings to form a file name. im creating a table to check if the file already exists. what I havent figured out yet is if I am better to make 1 88 character column or 3 smaller columns for searching.
this table will have millions of records.

I thought about using a script to check the filesystem for the filename but this must be accessed from multiple servers. I know I could call a php script on the server with the files but would also need to test this vs the MySQL table for performance.

the 3 strings are as follows:

```
file size = 8 bytes
md5 = 16 bytes
sha(256) = 64 characters.
```

the file extension is always the same so not included here.

Comment: I think it would be better to create single column and having an index on that column, rather than creating three different columns and creating composite index on those three columns which will take more space and time as compare to single index.

Comment: But how you are planning to keep 3 different information into single column? Won't you ever need this information separately?

Comment: MD5 is pretty junk these days, so if you can avoid it you really should. SHA2 is a bare minimum for any system designed to have a non-trivial lifespan.

Comment: This structure will depend on how you're accessing this data. Do you need to find files with a particular hash? If so, separate columns. If it's just a random value for naming purposes and you need to query by the full filename then a unified field is better.

Comment: The 3 values are gotten from the file on upload. They are then combined to form a unique file name based on the content.  table is only checked when uploading a new file to determine if it already exists.

Comment: tadman- I'm not using md5 by itself but in combination with sha256 for a slightly longer hash. But the original question should still get the same answer regardless of what 2 hashes I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 separate columns.

But... Just the MD5 is sufficient.  Because it is 128 bits,...  If you have 9 *trillion* rows, there is only one chance in 9 trillion of a false hit.  Since you have only a measly few million, the odds are much less.

I assume you are using `UNHEX()` on the md5 and using `BINARY(16)`?  (Similarly for sha256.)